# Can't create directory Magento 2.2.1

Tags: magento2.2, ultimo

Working on setting up a theme for Magento CE 2.2.1. Magento application is running in Centos 7.

Getting this error msg in report.

```
{"0":"Can't create directory \/var\/www\/html\/magento221\/generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/View\/Asset\/MergeService\/. in [Magento\\Framework\\View\\Asset\\MergeService\\Interceptor]","1":"#0 
\/var\/www\/html\/magento221\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Code\/Generator\/Autoloader.php(35): Magento\\Framework\\Code\\Generator->generateClass('Magento\\\\Framewo...')\n#1 [internal function]: Magento\\Framework\\Code\\Generator\\Autoloader->load('Magento\\\\Framewo...')\n#2 [internal function]: spl_autoload_call('Magento\\\\Framewo...')\n#3 \/var\/www\/html\/magento221\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Code\/Reader\/ClassReader.php(19): ReflectionClass->__construct('Magento\\\\Framewo...')\n#4
```

Gave full permissions to the var folder. 
chmod 777 var -R.
Manually cleared the cache, page_cache and view_processed folders.

Not sure, what is that I am missing. 
Looking for suggestions/advice.
Still a novice in Centos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento in version 2.2 moved `var/generation` to `generated` in root folder. You need to add access there as well.

Comment: Thank you so much. Some of the sub folders under generated was missing write permissions .. Fixed the problem.